# Nginx unexpectedly returns 404 for Nodejs API

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm trying to setup an VueJS frontend and a NodeJS api backend server with Nginx on Digital Ocean. I have been having trouble setting up Nginx to work correctly.

In more details what I'm trying to achieve:

- Accessing http://ipaddressordomain/ - returns Vuejs app.
- VueJS apps needs to send and pull data from backend which would be at http://ipaddressordomain/api, the Nodejs api works on port 3333 on the same server.

What actually happens:

- Accessing http://ipaddressordomain/ - returns Vuejs app without issue. VueJS seems to work ok.
- Vuejs cannot connect to backend api. Also accessing http://ipaddressordomain/api returns 404 via browser or Postman.

**CONFIGURATION**:

NodeJS api routes available routes should be http://myaddress/api on port 3333:

```
router.route("/api/:sid").get(getUrlShorten);
router.route("/ai").post(postUrlShorten);
```

Nginx configuration:

```
Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;


        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name lien.to;
        location / {
                root /var/www/html/liento-fe/dist;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3333/;
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
```

Firewall (UFW) :

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Also side-question: on DO the location proxy address should be localhost or the actual IP of the DO server?

What can I try next? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to remove the `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`:

```
location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3333/;
}
```

This works for me: https://github.com/gabrielwillemann/fast-help/blob/master/nginx/sites-avaible-examples.md#for-mutiple-proxies

Comment: thanks dude! that worked, i do get 502 error now but will try to solve that. I'm really noob and new to nginx and server setup but at least now I've got something out of the way :).